# EC2 ELB HTTPS Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elb

I have an EC2 server powering a HTTPS website for me through an Elastic Load Balancer. I want all connections to be forced through SSL up to the load balancer where the certificate is and then HTTP the rest of the way. Now I have gotten it partly working in that HTTPS terminates at the load balancer and continues onto the server as HTTP however if I attempt to connect to the load balancer using HTTP the site returns as a connection timeout error.

What I want is that if a user connects to the load balancer over a HTTP connection they are redirected to the HTTPS connection for that same domain.

I know that I can do this with rewrite rules in Apache but I want to get it done at the load balancer and not at the individual instance.

Comment: Unfortunately AWS does not expose such capabilities on their ELBs; you have to perform such HTTP redirects in your applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS ELB does not provide redirect feature. So all the redirects needs to be handles from the server side.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll add http processing to ELB and have apache redirect to https.